# How to get Application Context UiAutomator2 (Android)

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-uiautomator

To get context, I use:

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
```

But I didn't found any method like `getApplicationContext()`;

Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Your_Activity.this
```

Or you can create a public static method to get the Context:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Application sApplication;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return sApplication;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sApplication = this;
    }
}
```

Or get it through a View, using Your_View.getContext()
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply @Kyo Huu. Though I am looking for something that can be achieved from UiAutomator framework itself, rather than modifying the existing app code.